# Additional Question on "According to Hebrews 9:12, did the Lord Jesus Christ offer his blood in heaven?"

Tags: hebrews

Previous Question:  [According to Hebrews 9:12, did the Lord Jesus Christ offer his blood in heaven?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/6017/according-to-hebrews-912-did-the-lord-jesus-christ-offer-his-blood-in-heaven?rq=1)

The consensus answer to that previous question was that Jesus did not literally enter a literal temple in heaven and sprinkle His Holy blood there.  But the larger context is a comparison between two Covenants and two means of atonement, one temporary and one eternal.  In the first, the blood not only had to be shed, it had to be sprinkled.  Why would sprinkling be eliminated in the second?

Hebrews 9:11 states the heavenly temple is not made with human hands, which implies that it was made.  There is a literal temple in a literal heaven. The whole purpose of a temple is an altar and the whole purpose of an altar is a sprinkling.

So I ask: "What about the larger context?"  I worry the prior discussion could not see the forest for the trees.

Comment: Go ahead and link the previous question you're referring to here.  It will be easier to see what you're worrying about. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to BHSE! Please make sure you take our Tour. (See below left) Thanks.

Comment: So, to prevent this question being closed, what was it about the previous question that was not addressed.  Was it you did not find the answers satisfying or incomplete?

Comment: To hear the words of another, the words of the temple of the mind need sacrificed, therefore blood in the temple acts metaphorically. Those hearing while ready with the next saying never heard, and since they did not hear they did not see, but the teachings as Paul puts it, How to hear comes from the teachings of Jesus, and faith comes by hearing. -Romans 10:17

Comment: I disagree with the consensus answer being that it's not literal as it was repeated again in v. 23.  I think the larger context question is answered in it being literal.

Answer (score 2):

HEBREWS 9:11-12 (kjv) But Christ being come an high priest of good things to come, by a greater and more perfect tabernacle, not made with hands, that is to say, not of this building; Neither by the blood of goats and calves, but by his own blood he entered in once into the holy place, having obtained eternal redemption for us.

The tabernacle, the temple, were all made by man's hands.  Jesus ushered in a new era that has nothing to do with the buildings or the sacrificing of goats and calves as they did before Christ's resurrection.  By His blood that He shed on Calvary He entered into heaven once and for all having obtained eternal redemption for us.